# Using Safari 5.1.4, code blocks are empty on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting, code-block, safari

Code blocks on Stack Overflow (lines beginning with 4 whitespaces) with Safari v5.1.4 are empty/blank (even with the inspector, indicating it's populated via javascript).  If I use another browser (i.e. Chrome), they have content.

Using the same browser (Safari v5.1.4) on another Stack Exchange site, say Server Fault, doesn't have the same problem.

Since Safari v5.1.4 was just released, it's very possible it could be a problem with the browser.  But given the fact that two sites from Stack Exchange are showing different behaviour, I'd suspect the website at this point.

My browser is vanilla (no extensions/plug-ins).

Can others confirm this?!

When viewing the question [NSregularExpression and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683656/nsregularexpression-and-password) I get the following warning (but I don't believe it's related):

```
pixel;r=627855533;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;fpan=0;fpa=P0-1610253758-1313464351283;ns=0;ce=1;je=1;sr=1680x1050x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1331643039578;tzo=240;ref=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F;url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9683656%2Fnsregularexpression-and-password;ogl=:-1
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right place for bug reports :)

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in the Console tab? (As an aside, as apparently you're peeking into the DOM: it's [not really populated using JavaScript](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F9536250%2Fhow-do-i-temporarily-prevent-nstablecolumn-from-establishing-bindings-to-an-ns&http=1.1&type=GET&uak=0), but apparently something breaks when [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) kicks in? Safari 5.1.3 does not have any issue.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Safari 5.1.4 build 7534.54.16 on Windows 7/64. What OS are you using?

Comment: @balpha, on OSX.  Can't give you the build number at the moment.

Comment: @balpha, I've just upgraded too. No issues for me on the latest OS X (10.7.3 Lion, build 11D50b), Safari 5.1.4 (7534.54.16). I've not rebooted yet (which, officially, is not required for this update either). Stack Overflow is at rev 2012.3.13.1634 while I'm writing this. No changes when I log out, nor when I refresh the cache. All seems fine on my Mac.

Comment: @Arjan.  I tried rebooting and it seemed to have resolved it!!  Very weird.

Comment: @Arjan.  Nevermind.  The issue is back.  I'll try to figure out what triggers it.

Comment: Can you confirm Alex's 32-bit mode problem?

Comment: @Arjan, I was indeed in 32-bit mode (I also forget why).  Code blocks appear, but I'll let this work for a day and see if it re-occurs.  Thanks

Comment: @Arjan Same for me. Switching to 64-bit mode solves this problem — though it makes me unable to use some older plugins that have no 64-bit support…

Comment: (Safari 5.1.5 [might fix this](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1070), but I have not updated yet.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reported the same issue via the 'contact us' link at the bottom of Stack Overflow. I haven't gotten a response, but I imagine they are working on it. When you work on the cutting edge, expect blood! :)

I quit Safari and looked at its info window in the Finder. It was in 32-bit mode (I set it as 32-bit for some reason which escapes me at the present moment). I restarted Safari in 64-bit mode and it appears that this helped fix the code block issue. Can someone else try this out and see if they see the same fix?

[image]

The [Safari 5.1.5 release notes](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1070) state *"Safari 5.1.5 contains a fix for an issue that could affect website usability when running Safari in 32-bit mode"* so that hopefully fixes this for those who need 32-bit mode.

(Thanks to [Macintouch readers](http://www.macintouch.com/readerreports/safari5/index.html#d15mar2012) for providing the inspiration to try out this mode change. This also appears to fix other issues with Safari 5.1.4.)

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in the Web Inspector's Console tab?

Comment: Safari 5.1.4 is stable release, so I wouldn't call this "cutting edge"...

Comment: It looks like Apple made some major changes with the new JS engine. It's "cutting edge" in that sense, definitely. But to answer Arjan's question: no, there are no errors reported in the Console.

Comment: In the future, please just post bug reports like this here on meta. We like to be shamed publicly :)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm your 32 bit mode problems. In that case, I very clearly see the code on page load, but disappear right away. (That solves this, @balpha, I guess.)

Comment: Actually, the code disappears when the web socket for the notifications is opened. Until then, all is fine. I will fire up an old Mac that doesn't support 64-bit to start with. To be continued, @balpha.

Comment: Bravo, fixed my problem!

Comment: No issue in Safari 5.1.4 on a 32-bit 2006 Snow Leopard Mac (nor in some older version, which I did not correctly write down). I do not see web sockets being used in the Safari's Web Inspector's console log (like I do in Safari on Lion). Safari does support web sockets on 32 bit, but SE does not seem to use it? (On Chrome, `WebSocket` yields `function WebSocket() { [native code] }`, but in Safari it's `WebSocketConstructor`. However, that's the same on 64-bit, so I doubt that matters.) (ping @balpha, FYI.)

Comment: Was running in 32-bit, Lion, I think because of Slingbox Player. Resetting Safar to run 64 bit worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Never would have guessed in a hundred years.  I don't even remember why I would have ever set 32-bit mode in the first place :).

Answer (score 0):

I could constantly reproduce the problem, even after re-launching Safari.

In the comments above, Arjan mentioned the exact same build numbers I had, mentioned he also hadn't rebooted and couldn't reproduce the issue.  This made me **try to reboot**... and now it's resolved.

I feel somewhat sheepish now!  Rebooting might sound obvious to some but from where I'm standing, having to reboot is the exception.

**Edit**:  Premature celebration.  The issue is back.  I'll try to figure out how to better reproduce it.

Comment: *"from where I'm standing, having to reboot is the exception."* Don't feel bad. It's called being a Mac user.

Answer (score 0):

Declining this but as it seems to be a quirk with Safari and not the site.